# how to get radio button selected with data from mySql

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to make my radio button in edit form get selected with data from mySql, how can i write in radio button value ?

here is my code :

```
foreach($arrAnswer as $ans)
{           
  <input name = "answer_'.$i.'" type="radio"  value="'..'"> '.$ans->descript.'<br>
}
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question a bit. Post the contents of $arrAnswer for example, and on what condition do you want the radio button to be checked. That should help you solve it yourself even.

Comment: @jeoj  here's the $arrAnswer content    $arrAnswer = $this->m_pertanyaan_sensus->getJawaban($id);

Comment: @franklin, well and the contents of $this->m_pertanyaan_sensus->getJawaban($id); would be? try to add the output of var_dump( $arrAnswer ); if it's too big just the important parts

Answer (score 0):

```
Use can set radio box checked as shown below

 if ($fetch['sex'] = 'male')
    {
    echo "<td><input type='radio' name='sex' value='male' id='sex' checked> Male <input type='radio' name='sex' value='female' id='sex'> Female </td>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<td><input type='radio' name='sex' value='male' id='sex'> Male <input type='radio' name='sex' value='female' id='sex' checked> Female </td>";
    }
```

Comment: but i want these value selected with data from database, in my case the radio button is dynamic not like 'yes' or 'no'

Answer (score 0):

So I think this should work

```
$dummyAnswer = new stdClass();
$dummyAnswer->value = "somevalue";
$dummyAnswer->description = "some description";

$secondDummyAnswer = new stdClass();
$secondDummyAnswer->value = "second somevalue";
$secondDummyAnswer->description = "second some description";

// just a dummy, here would be your database result array
$arrAnswer = array(
    $dummyAnswer,
    $secondDummyAnswer
);

//wherever that comes from
$selectedValue = "somevalue";

foreach($arrAnswer as $index => $ans) {
    $checked = ( $ans->value == $selectedValue )? "checked" :"";

    echo '<input name = "answer_'.$index.'" type="radio"  value="'.$ans->value.'" '.$checked.'> '.$ans->description.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: i wanna try..it's a great idea with declare $checked, thank you @swidmann

Answer (score 0):

This is where the ternary operator comes in handy:

```
$checked = (statement here) ? 'checked' : '';
```

Replace `(statement here)` with your boolean value (1 or 0), such as `$ans->field_name_here`

Then put `$checked` inside your `<input>` tag, and ensure the value of the input is `1`:

```
<input name = "answer_'.$i.'" type="radio"  value="1" '.$checked.'> '.$ans->descript.'<br>
```

Comment: No problem. Also the code in your question appears to be missing quotes and `$html .=` or `echo`.